# Put multiple data in HBase with one command or at once

Tags: shell, hadoop, insert, hbase, put

Hi i want to put many data into HBase.
I work with the shell, i use the put command but inserting data one by one makes the work slow. Is there any other command to put many data in one command or reuse the put command at once.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load in Bulk you need to create **HFiles** with available data and put into HDFS notifying the Region Server

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#completebulkload